# post only after confirming email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, authentication

Guys in Rails how do I implement confirmation emails such that a nonuser can post only after confirming the email. So any regular person without an account views the site, submits post, verifies email and then the post is active. I already have devise installed but it seems its more for authenticating users. Whats the approach to take to implement the feature above and is there a specific gem to use?

Comment: My answer depended on you having authentication (so I deleted it). You will have a problem: Once an email is "confirmed" how do you stop me posting as someone else by claiming I am them just by using their email address? Avoid use of word "validated" here, it means that the address conforms to standard format, not that someone is on the other end of it.

Comment: :) Im glad you guys are definitely understanding the user is not authenticated in this scenario. Neil: My goal is that once the email is confirmed, other users won't be able to claim that email because they will have to click on the confirmation email they will not get since they do not own the email. Yes you can try to make a post with an email already claimed but the system won't ever post it because you won't ever confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

i think you will need to think in a different way
in your posts list/show actions you can show posts for active users, so if users didn't confirm their account their posts won't be displayed and once they confirm their posts will be shown automatically.

Comment: OP does not appear to have accounts as such, just email addresses associated with posts.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot specify a gem (and that is off topic).

Typically you generate a unique and unguessable (long and random) token, store it along with the entity that it finalises, have a route in your app that can accept the token and set a flag in the associated entity (in your case the post). Then construct the confirmation link that invokes that route - including the token data that you just generated - to put in the email.

You might add two fields to the posts table (that you keep hidden from the web page):

- email_confirm_token (indexed unique string)
- email_confirmed (bool)

And only display posts that have email_confirmed set.

The Ruby standard lib `SecureRandom` class is a good source of token data.

If you want to verify more than one type of entity, you might want to factor this out. The concept is sometimes called a "nonce"

Answer (score 0):

I guess devise' confirmable module can be used for the same. Devise is not just for authenticating . Just like :database_authenticatable for authentication, :confirmable is to verify if an account is already confirmed.

More details on using confirmable can be seen here [DeviseConfirmable](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb)

Comment: oh i thought he was using this option and needed to link it with posts activation